# Constrained sorting

Tags: combinatorics

The problem:
Let $a=(x,y)$ be a 2-tuple, such that $x,y<2m$ and $x+y$ is odd. We are given $2n$ tuples, half have $x$ odd and the other half have $x$ even, we also know $n_{xy}$, the count of each $(x,y)$-tuple. In how many ways can those $2n$ tuples be sorted s.t. the second element of a tuple equals the first element in the subsequent tuple.

This feels like a count of graph bijections problem. I wonder if I am just blind and this maps to a known problem? Assuming $m$ is known.

Comment: What does "the count of each $(x,y)$-tuple" mean?

Comment: The count of tuples of the form (x,y) given that need to be sorted as described.

Comment: Here "sorted" may be a poor choice of wording, leading many Readers to think you are asking about sorting algorithms.  I think you are asking about the number of possible *arrangements* of the $2n$ "tuples" (ordered pairs) so that "the second element of a tuple equals the first element in the subsequent tuple."  Such a "domino" sequencing of the ordered pairs is a graph path problem (rather than "graph bijections" perhaps).  It is not clear to me at a glance how much can be deduced from the limited information available.

Comment: I wanted to formulate it with dominoes but it requires them to be directional which makes the description less intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a graph with all integers $< 2m$, where you connect $(x, y)$ by a number of directed edges equal to $n_{x, y}$, you get a (non-simple) graph. You are asking essentially: how many Hamiltonian paths are there in this graph?

You have a bipartite graph due to the condition that $x + y$ is always odd, but even then [this problem is NP-hard](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18335/proof-that-the-existence-of-a-hamilton-path-in-a-bipartite-graph-is-np-complete), so unfortunately it does not help you. (In fact, this is kind of obvious: in any graph, you could subdivide each edge, giving you a bipartite graph whose Hamiltonian paths correspond one-to-one to the original graph's Hamiltonian paths.)

Comment: Yes, that isn't surprising. Thanks. However, if $m$ is known, would that change the answer? When $m\equiv 1$ it is trivial, what about 2?

Comment: If $m$ is fixed I would guess the problem becomes "tractable" -- i.e. polynomial in the other variables: you can check what cycles you can make with what edges in the graph, and then do something DP-like. (To work out the details  would be a lot of work though, and the degree of the polynomial would be very high.)

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question.

Comment: E.g. if $m = 2$, you have four nodes in your graph, so you could keep an array which has a dimension for each pair of nodes (fixed number), one dimension to keep track of the target and one dimension to keep track of the source, and let the value of the array be "How many paths are there from source to target using up precisely $k$ of the edges of type $x,y$ (where $n$ is the value in the $x, y$ dimension)." For $m = 2$ this array would be 18-dimensional, and I think naively filling it gives you a polynomial of order 22. (Of course this is highly redundant.)